# Usage of "pragmatic" vs. "practical"

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

As adjectives in **general usage** (not in jargon terminology), are the words *pragmatic* and *practical* synonymous? If not, how do their meanings and proper usage differ?

Comment: 'Cognitive synonymy' is usually met with in the question "Are x and y 'true synonyms' (ie completely interchangeable)?". We've found perhaps 1 pair of examples here. With your pair, the term 'pragmatic marker' doesn't accept the swap. A 'pragmatic joke' is unacceptable. 'Pragmatic' can have the different denotation 'pertaining to affairs of state' (and a weasel use of this has been made) ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The term "practical joke" is more of an idiom or phrasal noun, don't you think? It has a meaning completely different from "a joke that is practical" (in the same sense as "a plan that is practical").

Comment: And "pragmatic marker" is a linguistics jargon term that would never be encountered in general usage, and therefore outside the scope of my question.

Comment: @Rathony: Sorry that you overlooked the explicit qualification "in general usage, not jargon" that appeared in the question as originally written. I've refactored the question to make this more readily apparent.

Comment: And you edited the question just to remove the period from "vs."? Eyeroll.

Comment: 'Are *pragmatic* and *practical* fully interchangeable (as [cognitive synonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_synonymy)), or are there shades of difference between them such that there are  ... ?' conflicts with '(in general usage, not [jargon])': either you're talking cognitive synonyms (words always interchangeable **in all senses**) or you're not. '[A] word is cognitively synonymous with another word if and only if all instances of both words express the same exact thing ... which means that the words' interchangeability is not context-sensitive.' (your Wikipedia article).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that it is clear that _pragmatic_ and _practical_ are not cognitive synonyms. You said that we've found perhaps one pair of examples here, which example do you mean?

Comment: I forget who suggested them, but 'abstruse' and 'recondite'. Even here, you could argue that register differentiates.

Answer (score 9):

Let me start with my general sense based on usage that I've read and heard. To me, *pragmatic* refers to how something is realistic, sensible, and deliberately so. *Practical* is similar, but has more to do with actually doing something, and being effective. Also, *pragmatic* is more likely to be an attribute of a person. *Practical* could equally be a person or an idea.

Let's compare the definitions (from Merriam-Webster):

- **pragmatic**: dealing with the problems that exist in a specific situation in a reasonable and logical way instead of depending on ideas and theories.
- **practical**: relating to what is real rather than to what is possible or imagined / likely to succeed and reasonable to do or use / appropriate or suited for actual use.

So here we have a contrast between an idea of being "logical" (pragmatic) versus being "real" (practical).

It's also worth noting that the adjective pragmatic is also related to the philosophical idea of *pragmatism* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatism), where the noun *practicality* clearly doesn't contain the same connotation.

For this reason alone, the words are not true cognitive synonyms. At best, one might consider *certain usages/definitions* of these words to be cognitive synonyms of each other, but in any event there are counter examples. Practicality/Pragmatism is just one example. A practical joke (*pragmatic joke) is another. (Thanks Edwin Ashworth for this latter example.)

In terms of usage where one is clearly more appropriate, I would consider the following sentences:

> - She loved him and needed to see him again, and so she did the only **practical** thing she could do: she sold her car and bought a plane ticket to go visit him.
> - Her **practical** implementation of the theory formed the basis for further research.

In the first example, the woman is acting (at least in part) out of something more than just logic. She is taking *real* action, even if it's not pragmatic. In the second, its the "real" aspect of the implementation (versus theory) that makes "practical" the better word choice.

As a side note...this doesn't really answer your question, but it's interesting to note that *practical* is used dramatically more frequently than *pragmatic* (see [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pragmatic%2Cpractical&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpragmatic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpragmatic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPragmatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpractical%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpractical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPractical%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPRACTICAL%3B%2Cc0)). I wouldn't go so far as to say that *pragmatic* will die out in favor of *practical* (if anything the usage of these words is actually converging), but I suspect that *practical* will continue to be the more popular word for the foreseeable future.

Comment: I think you explained very well on *practical*'s practical usages.

Comment: Nice explanation, which seems to share some aspects in common with mine but certainly goes further

Comment: The use of *Pragmatism* as the name for a school of philosophy comes under the exclusion of "jargon" (use in a specialized context) that I excluded in my question. (In fact, I had that specifically in mind when I wrote the exclusion.) So that part of your answer is not germane to the question.

Comment: Fair enough. I would still argue that the words are not cognitive synonyms, even if one only includes the "principal" non-jargon definition of each word. But thanks for clarifying what you consider in-scope for "jargon."

Comment: I question jdmc's assertion that "pragmatism," even if used to describe a philosophical movement, constitutes "jargon." Is "absolutism" jargon because it is often used in history? Is "arpeggio" jargon because it is used in "music"? The fact that Webster's has the meaning of "confused, unintelligible language" as part of its primary meaning indicates to me that the sense of jargon in this context is that it's language that is often deliberately used to obscure meaning by the members of a particular group (as is ubiquitous in, say, the corporate or computer world).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. They are relatively close synonyms, but I'd say "practical" is the more all-purpose, general word while "pragmatic" is more specific and related to a way of thinking. Pragmatism is, for instance, a philosophical line of thinking that eschews symbolic representations and ideas in favor of real instruments or, according to Webster's is:

> a reasonable and logical way of doing things or of thinking about
>   problems that is based on dealing with specific situations instead of
>   on ideas and theories

The adjective "pragmatic" is:

> : dealing with the problems that exist in a specific situation in a
>   reasonable and logical way instead of depending on ideas and theories

"Practical" is:

> relating to what is real rather than to what is possible or imagined

Both quite close, but as you can see there seems to be bit of a connotative difference, with "pragmatic" being a bit more academic. I'd probably argue that while pragmatic seems more related to a line of thought, practical refers to actions. For one thing, you seem to always hear someone say "Be practical" but you don't seem to hear "Be pragmatic."

Comment: The general/academic aspect and the thought/action aspect are useful and helpful distinctions. Good explanation.

Comment: While it's true that *practical* is used more frequently than *pragmatic*, that alone doesn't imply that advice to "be pragmatic" or to "be practical" would have any difference in meaning.

Comment: @jdmc -- It's generally a good idea to read more carefully before commenting; I never say anything about practical being used "more frequently" (nor do I necessarily think it's the case).

Answer (score 2):

methinks that the wannabe-considered well-read types and writers for TV-talkers have recently started substituting "pragmatic" in place of "practical" ...because it sounds more important + it (purposely) obscures their meaning -since no one knows why they are substituting the high-highfalutin-sounding, similar-but-incorrect word for the simple, normal and sensible one.

Comment: Why the -1? I agree that this is happening way too much: To "leverage" something, instead of plain ol' "use", or even "take advantage of" something. To assist someone, instead just helping them. To "revert" to someone with some business information, than than replying to them. (Of course, "revert" does not mean what the sender intends to say in this case. However, it's well worth using poor English to avoid the risk of appearing uneducated). Have a +1 to (partially) undo the bad karma that is seems the "wannabe-considered well-read types" are trying to force on you here :)

Answer (score 1):

*Pragmatic* and *practical* are only synonyms in one sense: when describing something **guided by practical experience and observation rather than theory.**

*Practical* can be used to say a result or a thing has some quality in almost every respect. Pragmatic doesn't have this definition. ie. *a practical failure* or *Tim is a practical wizard when it comes to coding.*

You can also use *practical* to describe something put to a practical purpose or use. You can say *practical applications of calculus* but to say *pragmatic applications of calculus* is another thing entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes from [this definition][1], where *pragmatism* is described as: "action or policy dictated by consideration of the immediate practical consequences".

I interpret that as: You can discuss an approach on solving a problem pragmatically; knowing the cause and effects of the 'parameters' being discussed. Like: if we investigate the issue first to find a root cause, the chance of applying a solution that actually works is higher.

Now consider being practical (without being pragmatical) about solving a problem: you just start doing something differently. It is about the doing part, doing is practical. Thinking is not practical. It comes from the word practice. You do not practise soccer by thinking, but by 'doing' the soccer. Being practical about soccer is actually playing soccer.

Being pragmatic about soccer is like knowing that if you sprint too fast too soon in the game (to outrun your opponent), you may be too tired too soon to give a good directional kick on the ball to get it in the goal, when you get a good chance to do so. You do not need to play soccer at the moment you are pragmatic about it. SO being pragmatic about soccer is that you would save your energy for a better chance later in the game, for instance.

But maybe this is just my interpretation. I like this one better than just interchangeably using the words practical/pragmatical, because then there is no distinction.

I think the confusion comes from from people who like to discuss problems, and come up with exotic ideas, to which people reply: "let's be pragmatic." Not meaning to start doing something right away, but rather stay more close to one's experience to come up with solutions, rather than dreaming exotic ideas that could be just fun to try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Mike, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

> Practical - doable or relating to actions in real
>   world

I will say pragmatic is a theory which is practical

> Pragmatic - relating to practically verified theory i.e verified practically that the theory is true

When you say ***a book is practical***, the book shows the way to do actions.
When you say ***a book is pragmatic***, the book has the theory which is verified that it can be converted to actions.

Answer (score 0):

To me a *pragmatic* solution/decision would be a *wise*, *feasible* one, based on *common sense*.

A *practical* solution could be as above, but most of all it's *smart* and *inventive*, maybe *ergonomic*.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the discussion above, I'll attempt an example of sorts: You may have several practical (hands-on, concrete) options to solve a problem you are facing, but you make a pragmatic decision about which one to go with, i.e. a decision that is logically/strategically speaking the best suited to your goals, aims, and needs at that point (and that may even depend on an agenda that is not obvious to others and perhaps not even related directly to the problem itself).